# Add a NuGet project reference .Net Core

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

So, I was playing with .Net core and decided to migrate my very small framework helper to it. Nothing fancy, just a few helper classes. The thing is, I simply can't get my dll to be referenced into other projects.

I have created a nupkg file using VS2017 "Generate NuGet package on build" and added it to my project. But VS loaded all the dependencies, but not my dll. It also added the dependencies twice.

Here are a couple of pictures of my config. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the project file for both the library and the application trying to consume it, as *text* in the question rather than screenshots. Ideally cut this down to a [mcve] so we can reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: The Solution explorer clearly shows that `Framework.Core` is a dependency of `Ecominas.Domain`. So, can you explain what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Even though the explorer says that, I cannot use any of the content from Framework.Core. Not even a simple "using Framework;" works. VS keeps saying that I forgot an assembly reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently, that "-rc1" in the version was screwing things.

So, I just changed the version to 0.9.0 instead of 1.0.0-rc1 and everything works fine.

Take care :)